# Swipe between XIB

Tags: ipad

I use button to switch between XIB. My function is like this:

```
 -(IBAction)swapViews; { 
     SecondViewController *second2 =[[SecondViewController alloc
         initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
     second2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
     [self presentModalViewController:second2 animated:YES];
     [second2 release];
 }
```

How I can use swipe between XIB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to swipe between the two views, you should not present them modally (`presentModalViewController`).

Have a look at `[UIScrollView][1]` and at this [simple tutorial](http://idevzilla.com/2010/09/16/uiscrollview-a-really-simple-tutorial/).

In short, you should create your `UIScrollView`, which will manage the swipe for you, then add all the views you want to manage through swipe to the `UIScrollView` as subviews.

```
 - (void)loadView {
     [super loadView];
     UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,     self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
     scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;

     FirstViewController *first =[[FirstViewController alloc initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
     [scroll addSubview:first.view];

     SecondViewController *second =[[SecondViewController alloc initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
     [scroll addSubview:second.view];

     scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
     [self.view addSubview:scroll];
     [scroll release];
```

}

Comment: no problem. Look at my edit... I am loading two xibs and placing them in a scroll view... does it make sense to you?